# 1-million-row ListView

Tags: windows, listview, user-interface, winapi, syslistview32

I have a `SysListView32` that should potentially host millions of rows, and three columns of text A, B, C each < 256 characters.

Let's say column B has many many repetitions (example: column A is filename, column B is path, and each row is a file of the filesystem), and has only 100k different values (instead of several millions).

**Is it possible to avoid duplication in RAM of content of column B of the `ListView` GUI element?**

Can we fill a `ListView` with only *pointers* to arrays elements (taken from the 100k-element-array of different values of column B), instead of duplicated data?

How to modify this to make it work?

```
LV_ITEM item;
item.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
item.pszText = "Hello";
...
ListView_SetItem(hList, &item);
```

Comment: [Virtual List-View Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style) and [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Looks interesting indeed, I read it a few times, but I'll probably need 10 more readings to fully get it. Maybe do you think we could find a full MSVC++ toy project that demonstrates this, with a real concrete ListView filled with rows?

Comment: There isn't much to it, really. You create a list-view using the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style, store a pointer to the raw data in `LVITEM.lParam`, and handle the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message.

Comment: I frequently do. Now you know what to research, you'll solve this with ease.

Comment: @IInspectable `store a pointer to the raw data in LVITEM.lParam` this is mistake for virtual list. it not allocate data for items and not store any *lParam*. need use `NMLVDISPINFO.item.iItem`

Comment: @Basj - create list with `LVS_OWNERDATA`, call `ListView_SetItemCountEx` and handle `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification - based on `(NMLVDISPINFO*)lParam)->item.iItem` - in what problem

Comment: for use `LVITEM.lParam` - need that list view allocate memory for all items and you call  `ListView_SetItem` for every item for set *lParam* - this is not virtual list view. virtual when list view not store any data for items. - it simply store it count and ask you for data via `LVN_GETDISPINFO` and you can use only `iItem` (item number) here for return data

Comment: but look for [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx) - in `LVN_GETDISPINFO` handler - `RetrieveItem( &rndItem, plvdi->item.iItem );` called - you need implement own `RetrieveItem` for get item info by index and return to list view - what here is unclear ? and at begin you need call `ListView_SetItemCountEx` (exactly with Ex)

Comment: @Basj: start with Microsoft's own example - [How to Use Virtual List-View Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411.aspx): "*This topic demonstrates how to work with virtual list-view controls. The accompanying C++ code examples show how to process virtual list-view control notification messages, how to optimize the cache, and how to retrieve an item from the cache.*"

Comment: It seems I'm not the only one to have tried to understand this [with a bit of difficulty](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/702340/How-do-I-create-a-Virtual-Listview-with-Cplusplus), but the given solution there seems not to apply here.

Comment: Sheesh. There's are loads of resources out there if you search. If you spent more time making an effort to learn, and less time begging for somebody to spoon feed you you'd make faste le progress. Sometimes I think that SO just makes matters worse by encouraging this vampiric spoon feed me attitude.

Comment: @Basj if you actually read the documentation carefully, it explains caching. The simplest example is when a ListView displays an entire array of data, so the entire array acts as the cache. Set the ListView item count to the array length and go, and use requested item indexes as array indexes. Things get much more interesting when you can't store all of the ListView items in memory at one time. Think large files, database record sets, etc. Caching becomes much more important for that. The ListView tells you which items it needs at any given time, so you can cache only those items in memory.

Comment: @Basj the top and bottom ListView items are frequently needed, not just for display but also for calculations and such, so it is best to always keep them cached. The rest of the caching involves only the ListView items that are actively displayed, and a little above and below for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is also referred as "Virtual List". A virtual list control is a list view control that has the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style. This style enables the control to support an item count up to a DWORD (the default item count only extends to an int). However, the biggest advantage provided by this style is the ability to only have a subset of data items in memory at any one time. This allows the virtual list view control to lend itself for use with large databases of information, where specific methods of accessing data are already in place. For a given set of data (list or dynamic array), you need to follow these steps:

1. Add LVS_OWNERDATA style to your ListView
2. Make a call to CListCtrl::SetItemCount passing the data source size, like std::vector::size().
3. Catch the LVN_GETDISPINFO notification. This is where the data is rendered into the ListCtrl.

Please have a look at the attached links I added, for more information and sample code. If you use CListView you can have access to the CListCtrl with [GetListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3ch0w2y.aspx#clistview__getlistctrl).

Links:

[Virtual List Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58.aspx)

[Using virtual lists](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists)

Comment: Thanks @RonTLV. Can you add some code as an example of how to do it?

Comment: @Basj [Using ListView control under Win32 API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win-API) + sources + demo project

Comment: @Basj [About List-View Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Using List-View Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774736(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It seems @RonTLV, that this code example doesn't show the *tricky part of the problem*, i.e. the virtual list aspect. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win-API) no LVS_OWNERDATA or LVN_GETDISPINFO is there. That was the real question: how to handle virtual lists.